# How to configure spring to send SMTP emails through Annotations without using XML?

Tags: java, spring, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I need to send SMTP emails, but I'd like to avoid to use XML to configure spring services and use annotations only.

How can I configure the whole SMTP sender and use it only by code and annotations?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With using org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper, like this:

```
JavaMailSenderImpl sender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
sender.setHost("mail.host.com");

MimeMessage message = sender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);
helper.setTo("test@host.com");
helper.setText("Thank you for ordering!");

sender.send(message);
```

Is this what you were looking for? Taken from http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mail.html, please have a look there to see some more advanced samples. (Attachments, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Use Autowiring

```
@Autowire
private JavaMailSender mailSender;
```

and in XML add the following lines:

```
   <context:annotation-config/> 
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.mail.javamail"/>
```

Refer documentation for more help.